# Follow up query, do not include already collected result

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Bit of a weird one

I've written in my Repository a search function that takes a string query.

In this, it runs a quick query, with a wildcard search on the entities title, looking for a match for the first bit of the title

Then I'm running a second query (because Doctrine2 does not support Unions) afterwards, to do a general wildcard search through the whole title.

Obviously this would mean that it's getting the same results as the previous query. So im looking to tell DQL in the second query, to ignore already acquired results.

Buuut, I just don't know how to provide that at all

Here's my search function:

```
    public function search($search) {

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
        $query->select('v')
            ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
            ->where($query->expr()->like('v.title', $query->expr()->literal(sprintf('%s%%', $search))));

        $set1 = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

        $query->where(
            $query->expr()->andX(
                $query->expr()->like('v.title', $query->expr()->literal(sprintf('%%%s%%', $search))),
                $query->expr()->notIn('v',  $set1) // Trying to provide the already acquired set of the results, to negate from this query
            )
        );

        $set2 = $query->getQuery()->getResult();

        $result = array_merge($set1, $set2);

        return $result;
    }
```

This right now doesn't work, because it's trying to convert the array to a string.

This may sound pretentious, but I'd like to avoid writing a loop along the first set just to extract an array of ID's to provide the second set to negate. I know DQL supports reading in full entity objects, and arrays of full objects, I'm sure I'm just not coming across the correct predicate method that knows how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can query by both where clauses, and return only DISTINCT entities.

```
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
    $query->select('v')
        ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'v')
        ->where($query->expr()->like('v.title', $query->expr()->literal(sprintf('%s%%',:search))))
        ->orWhere($query->expr()->like('v.title', $query->expr()->literal(sprintf('%%%s%%', :search))),
        ))
        ->setParameter('search', $search)
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: The problem with this approach however, is that the order at which the resulting records are acquired cannot be managed.  Results will be scattered amongst each-other. In a query for "Hell", a record with "And Hello There" might come before "Hell the Sequel", where im looking to have the exact title results shown first, before partial title matches, and so on and so fourth.  Which is why traditionally you'd use Union in this case to execute sub-queries which can be individually be controlled